# How can I open WSO2 Identity Server management console?

Tags: tomcat, wso2, wso2-identity-server

I really can't find anywhere in the website. Very frustrating. I'm running Apache Tomcat 8.0.32 version.

Comment: Can you explain what are you trying to setup? The WSO2 IS doc is here https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS580/WSO2+Identity+Server+Documentation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WSO2 Identity Server is a stand alone server and you do not require Apache Tomcat to run it. This document [1] explains how to start the Identity Server. After starting, management console is available under `https://localhost:9443/carbon/` URL.

[1] https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS580/Running+the+Product